# Session expires on iPad & Tablets unlike PC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ipad, asp.net-mvc-4, session, tablet

I am about to pull my hair on this! I have an MVC application, I have extended the session up to 2 hours, when I log in from any PC the session preserve the session for 2 hours, however when I log in from iPad or any tablet it only keeps the session for 1 hour!!

I have tried to do more investigation on this with no success. Tried to see if the firewall or proxy server is causing this, but it makes no sense! What can I do more?

**Edit:**

The code snippet which cause a redirection to login page after clicking on the link while waiting for 1 hour:

> ```
> @if (@TempData["IsOnTime"] != null)
> {
>     <a id="back" href="@Url.Action("Step1", "Home", new { id = Model.Id)"> Back </a>
> }
> ```

Comment: Can you show the actual code of session preservation?

Comment: I'm depending on a TempData to check whether I should redirect to a certain page or not.

Comment: Try Using `Session` variables,  and don't forget to nullify them when you exit the View or application. `TempData` has a  specific expiration time from what I know.